# Detect unique id of the hololens device

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, hololens

I would like to detect unique id of the hololens device (uwp application).
I tried to use [Eas​Client​Device​Information.Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation#Windows_Security_ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning_EasClientDeviceInformation_Id) but it is the same on the different devices for some reason.

Do you know how better to detect unique device?

I am using [GetSystemIdForPublisher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile.systemidentification) as alternative solution for now.

Thanks for help

Comment: What is the problem with GetSystemIdForPublisher? It seems perfectly suitable for your usecase.

Comment: Yes, according to the documentation it is. I just want to know if the same id is bug in case of Device​Information.Id or I missed something in documentation (since it is also suitable for my case according to the doc).

Comment: Officially there doesn't seem to be, it's worth nothing Windows Mobile 10 returns the same value for most devices too (and EasClient isn't universal without Extension SDK's), so the above is preferred.